# Getting the sequenced id of a row to be the foreign key of a row in another table in one query

Tags: sql-server, local-variables, tsql-sequence

The database is SQL Server 2012.

I'm supposed to add a bunch of rows on two tables from an Excel file.

I have the table `Customers`:

```
id | firstname | lastname
1  | John      | Doe
etc.
```

The `Customers` table has a sequence `customers_seq` to use for ids for new rows. Because at the time of insertion the amount of rows is not known. As follows:

```
    insert into Customers (id,firstname,lastname)
    values
    (next value for customers_seq, '2016-001', 'John', 'Doe'),
    (next value for customers_seq, '2016-002', 'Jane', 'Doe'),
    (next value for customers_seq, '2016-003', 'Steve', 'Waters'); 
-- tons of more customers --
```

This works as intended.

I also have the table `Services`

```
id | name | fk_Customers
1  | lunch| 2
etc.
```

**Now, here's the problem:**

I'm supposed to - in that same query where I add the `Customers` rows- to add a row on the table `Services` after each row added to the table `Customers` so, that the sequence-generated `id` for the `Customers` row would become the value for the column `fk_Customers` on the row that is added to the `Services` table.

I was thinking it might be possible by using the TSQL Local variables.

So, something like:

```
DECLARE @sequenceCreatedId bigint;  
SET @sequenceCreatedId = next value for customers_seq; 

insert into Customers (id,firstname,lastname)
values(@sequenceCreatedId, '2016-001', 'John', 'Doe')

insert into Services (id,name,fk_Customers)
values(next value for services_seq, someName, @sequenceCreatedId);

--And just repeat that whole thing. Setting that variable again and again--

SET @sequenceCreatedId = next value for customers_seq; 

insert into Customers (id,firstname,lastname)
values(@sequenceCreatedId, '2016-002', 'Jane', 'Doe')

insert into Services (id,name,fk_Customers)
values(next value for services_seq, anotherName, @sequenceCreatedId);
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, use the `inserted` portion of the [output clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) to get all of them at once:

```
declare @customers table (
    id int not null identity(0, 1)
  , firstname nvarchar(100) not null
  , lastname nvarchar(100) not null
);

insert into @customers (firstname, lastname)
output inserted.*
values ('John', 'Doe')
     , ('Jane', 'Doe')
     , ('Steve', 'Waters');
```

My example doesn't use a sequence but it'll work the same way. Note that this will work for an `update` or `delete` as well; one can even get the old and new values in one shot using both `deleted` and `inserted`:

```
update a
   set a.FirstName = Convert(nvarchar(100), NewId())
output deleted.FirstName as OldFirstName
     , inserted.FirstName as NewFirstName
from @customers as a;
```